# Where can I get 32 bit version of IESHIMS.dll and GPSVC.dll which will be compatible with Windows Server?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, windows-server-2008

I am facing one problem that my 32 bit ocx doesn't get register on Windows Server 2008R2.

After using the dependency walker I came to knew that 32 bit version of GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.dll are missing on R2 OS. So I tried to search the 32 bit versions of these dll for R2 on net but did not find these dlls. So can any body tell me whether 32 bit versions for these dll are present or not which can be used on R2 OS?

Answer (score 0):

try to run regsrv32 to your dll.

ref : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/8a751f65-ade9-4b8b-a3d3-c720ccbd3d2c/ieshimsdll-missing?forum=w7itproinstall

Answer (score 0):

> After using the dependency walker I came to knew that 32 bit version of GPSVC.dll and IESHIMS.dll are missing on R2 OS. So I tried to serach the 32 bit versions of these dll for R2 on net but did not find these dlls.

Dependency walker often reports missing DLLs for modules that execute fine. Certainly it is common to see that ieshims.dll is missing according to Dependency Walker, but the module in question works perfectly well.

So, it is highly likely that you have mis-diagnosed your problem. You will not solve the problem by finding these DLLs because they are almost certainly not the reason for the failure. You'll need to debug the registration failure to find out what the true cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

What software on your computer needs the 32bit of [IESHIMS.dll](https://coding.fm/ieshims.dll/) and GPSVC.dll?
If the software is not compatible with Windows Server 2008, you may need to contact the vendor of the software to get a compatible one.
By the way, you may try to copy them from a 64bit of Windows 7, however, this will not be supported by Microsoft.